# Delete user profile

Tags: autonomy, interwoven, imanage

Is it possible to delete a `WorkSite` user using the API?

I have the following dlls referenced.

```
IManage.dll
IMANADMIN.dll
IMANEXTLib.dll
```

I can create a user using `IMANADMIN.NRTDatabase.CreateUser()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Worksite` doesn't allow delete a user.

Only `rename` via `DbAdmin` (It's not possible do it using `iManage API`) to another user or disable him.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it isn't possible to do via API
You may only forbid user to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

IMANADMIN.NRTDatabase.DeleteUser()

Comment: Do you mean using a new release of Worksite? We are using 8.5

Comment: I'm using 9.0 and `DeleteUser()` function doesn't exists. I asked the same question to Autonomy/HP support that also said that isn't possible to delete a user via API or even via `DbAdmin`.

Comment: I'm using Release 10.0. Much better. Hope that helps. Clyde.